# JAVA - Hangman game that keeps the correct letter entered in the unknown letters

Tags: java, loops

```
 if(letterGuessBoolean == true) {
      System.out.println("Nice job! That was correct!");
      for (position = 0; position < pickRandomWord.length(); position++) {
        if (pickRandomWord.charAt(position) == letterGuess) {
          System.out.print(letterGuess);
        } 
        else {
          System.out.print(unknownLetters);
        }
      }
    }
```

loop does save the word properly, the unknown character never save the correct way.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the updateLetterGuess = letterGuess; it does nothing and  forgot to delete it.

Comment: Might need to see the rest of the code, how are the guessed letters stored?

Comment: I don't see anything that's assigning a variable outside incrementing the index for a for loop. Can you show us a bit more of your code?

Comment: @BlueBoy Yes I updated it.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out the latestly guessed letter only, because this is the only thing you are checking:

```java
pickRandomWord.charAt(position) == letterGuess
```

You need to remember somehow and somewhere, which letters have been guessed previously. One variant could be the following:

```java
String pickRandomWord = ""; // select your random word
char[] displayOutput = new char[pickRandomWord.length()];
for(int n = 0; n < displayOutput.length; ++n)
    displayOutput[n] = '-';

/* ... */

if(letterGuessBoolean) // do not compare against true, if it is already boolean!
{
    for(int position = 0; position < pickRandomWord.length(); ++position)
    {
        if (pickRandomWord.charAt(position) == letterGuess)
        {
            displayOutput[position] = letterGuess;
        }
        System.out.print(displayOutput[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There i was thinking about boolean flags but with a char[] its probably 100x easier to just change the value. Thats overthinking it for you

Comment: @Aconcagua is there anyway I can message you really quick if you have the time? I think I almost have it but I still need help if that's alright?

Comment: @EvanVukasinovic Sorry, no, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users). Only option leaving comments here - or chat (but it is 2:45 here and I'm going to get some sleep now...).